# Are jiffies and cpu ticks the same?

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage

Are both cpu ticks and jiffies in a cpu the same or are they different if not can any one give me the difference between them
thanks in advance

Comment: See http://catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/J/jiffy.html for start.

Comment: thanks but can we find the number of cpu ticks in linux system